# How to use rosinstall to download git source?

Tags: ros, rosinstall, git

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to use the code,but failed:

```
  - git:
       uri: http://code.in.tum.de/git/cram-pl.git
       local-name:cram_pl
```

How to fixed it?

Thank you~

```
 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/rosinstall_auto$ rosinstall .      /opt/ros/diamondback ./cram_pl.rosinstall 
 rosinstall operating on /home/sam/code/ros/rosinstall_auto from      specifications in rosinstall files  /opt/ros/diamondback, ./cram_pl.rosinstall
 processing config_uri /opt/ros/diamondback
 ahhhhhhhh, yaml parse error: while scanning a simple key
   in "/home/sam/code/ros/rosinstall_auto/cram_pl.rosinstall", line 3, column      6
 could not found expected ':'
   in "/home/sam/code/ros/rosinstall_auto/cram_pl.rosinstall", line 4, column      1
 Usage: rosinstall PATH [<options> ...] [URI]... 
 
 rosinstall: error: None
 
 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/rosinstall_auto$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11085/how-to-use-rosinstall-to-download-git-source?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're missing a space between "local-name" and "cram_pl" (your error message complains about a YAML error on line 3)

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4